# Share datastore for different apps or host two languages in one app

Tags: google-app-engine, share, google-cloud-datastore

I am running a java application on the GAE and would like to use the matplotlib. After it is only available for python I considered two solutions:

- Run a second app in python and access the same datastore as my java app
  or
- host two programs of different languages in one app engine (e.g. two different versions)

Is this possible at all or is there a better way to realize this? Somehow I got in mind that there was something about sharing datastores at the I/O 2013. Unfortunately I didn't find anything on the web.

Comment: With release features, you could deploy python to a different version.  I think App Engine Servers will let you define different runtimes for frontends:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/vNrNnhAKcuk

Comment: or alternatively you can make web services to grab your datastore record.